# Delete Duplicate records and keep the latest one

Tags: mysql

[image: records]

I need to delete a record where vehicleId and vehiclePropertyValueVehicleProperNameId is repeated but need to keep the latest record.

Here is the ddl:

```
    CREATE TABLE `vehicleVehiclePropertyValue` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicleId` bigint NOT NULL,
  `vehiclePropertyValueId` bigint NOT NULL,
  `vehiclePropertyValueVehicleProperNameId` bigint NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deletedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vehicleId` (`vehicleId`),
  KEY `vehiclePropertyValueId` (`vehiclePropertyValueId`),
  KEY `vehiclePropertyValueVehicleProperNameId` (`vehiclePropertyValueVehicleProperNameId`),
  CONSTRAINT `vehicleVehiclePropertyValue_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicleId`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `vehicleVehiclePropertyValue_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`vehiclePropertyValueId`) REFERENCES `vehiclePropertyValue` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `vehicleVehiclePropertyValue_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`vehiclePropertyValueVehicleProperNameId`) REFERENCES `vehiclePropertyName` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=652567 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag from your question since you are apparently using MySQL instead of Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: okay, thanks) @DanGuzman

Comment: How big is the table; what percentage of rows will be tossed?  A DELETE with a JOIN will be fine for a small table; if things are big, another approach will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM vehicleVehiclePropertyValue t1
JOIN vehicleVehiclePropertyValue t2 
    USING (vehicleId, vehiclePropertyValueVehicleProperNameId)
WHERE t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
```

Use needed DATETIME column in WHERE.. or maybe even `id`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks)